# Channel never dies although closed

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

In the following code, i am trying to write all files that are sent to the `inputs` channel and send a corresponding response over the `operationOutcomes` channel

**main.go**

```
package main

import(
    lr "github.com/fabulousduck/librarian"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    writeOpCount := 100;
    operationOutcomes, inputs := make(chan lr.WriteOpResponse), make(chan lr.WriteOp)
    go lr.WriteC(inputs, operationOutcomes)

    for i := 0; i < writeOpCount; i++ {
        inputs <- lr.WriteOp{ Dest: `../exampleFiles/createdFiles/{i}.txt`, Content: `Invoice #{i}` }
    }

    close(inputs)  

    for i := 0; i < writeOpCount; i++ {
        writeResult := <-operationOutcomes
        fmt.Println("Response from write operation : ", writeResult.Msg, "err ", writeResult.Err, "bytes written : ", writeResult.BytesWritten)
    }

    close(operationOutcomes)
}
```

**librarian.go**
    package librarian

```
import(
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

type WriteOp struct {
    Dest, Content string
}

type WriteOpResponse struct {
    Msg error
    Err bool
    BytesWritten int
}

func WriteC (inputChannel <-chan WriteOp, outputChannel chan<- WriteOpResponse) {
    workOp :=  <-inputChannel
    go writeWorker(workOp, outputChannel)
}

func writeWorker (job WriteOp, outGoing chan<- WriteOpResponse) {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(job.Dest, os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err : ", err)
        outGoing <- WriteOpResponse{ Msg: err, Err: true, BytesWritten: 0 }
    }
    bytesWritten , err := file.WriteString(job.Content)
    if err != nil {
        outGoing <- WriteOpResponse{ Msg: err, Err: true, BytesWritten: 0 }
    }
    outGoing <- WriteOpResponse{ Msg: nil, Err: false, BytesWritten: bytesWritten } 
}
```

This throws a deadlock in both cases when there is and isn't an error, even though i am closing both channels when i am done with them ?

Comment: As a comment since it's not related to the q - since WriteC is already called as a goroutine, why does it start another goroutine to call `writeWorker`?

Comment: As you might want to add multiple instances of `writeC` in other parts of your code that are not related to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only read from `operationOutcomes` up to `writeOpCount` times, even though in `writeWorker` each execution can result in up to 3 messages being written on that channel (none of your error cases causes the function to return, to it continues processing). Because it's unbuffered and it stops being read, at some point the workers writing to it can no longer add messages and so lock forever.

Also, since you only call `WriteC` once and it does not loop, it will only ever read and process one message from the `inputs`. If `writeOpCount` is > 1, then it will lock forever within the first loop when it tries to queue a second message.

Comment: i have indeed noticed that, and tried adding `return` statements after each push to a channel. This however does not solve the problem.

Comment: Updated - spotted a second issue.

Comment: thank you very much. the second issue solved my problem.